# Show, that if $f_n \rightarrow f$ and $f_n \rightarrow g$ is $\mu$-convergent, then $f=g$ almost everywhere on $X$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

Show, that if $f_n \rightarrow f$ and $f_n \rightarrow g$ is $\mu$-convergent, then $f=g$ almost everywhere on $X$

*Hint*

Use the fact, that:

$$\left\{ x \in X \: : \: f(x) \neq g(x) \right\} = \bigcup_{m=1}^{\infty} \left\{ x \in X \: : \: |f(x) - g(x)| \ge \frac{1}{m} \right\}$$

---

So, I don't know how to use that hint. $\mu$ convergent means (correct me if I'm wrong), that

$$f_n \rightarrow f \text{ is }\mu\text{ convergent} \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad \mu(\left\{ x \in X \: : \: \forall_{\varepsilon} \quad \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} |f_n (x) - f(x)| > \varepsilon \right\}) = 0$$

So I don't see it how the hint should be used.

It is not written what kind of measure our $\mu$ is though, usually when there's nothing written we assume it's a Lebesgue measure, but I don't know if that has to be the case here

Comment: Imagine if $f$ and $g$ did not agree almost everywhere on $X$.  Then there's some region of nonzero measure where the absolute value of their difference is nonzero.  Can a positive nonzero function with nontrivial support have zero integral?

Comment: @user3716267 No, it can't. But what does this has to do with the hint we're given to use to solve the exercise?

Comment: The hint tells us $f_n$ and $f$ disagree on a set of arbitrarily small measure (as $n$ gets larger), and likewise for $f_n$ and $g$.  But we know from the above reasoning that $f$ and $g$ themselves disagree on a set of nontrivial measure.  Can you proceed from here?

Comment: @user3716267 Honestly, I don't have an idea how to proceed from here. My guess would be to take the measure $\mu$ from both sides so we have $\mu (\left\{ x \in X \: : \: f(x) \neq g(x) \right\}) = \mu( \bigcup_{m=1}^{\infty} \left\{ x \in X \: : \: |f(x) - g(x)| \ge \frac{1}{m} \right\})$ Then we need to show that the left side is gonna be equal to zero, thus meaning that $f$ and $g$ are equal a.e. But I don't know, this approach kinda seems wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would guess $\mu$-convergent means the sequences converge in measure, which means for every $\varepsilon > 0$, $\mu(x \in X : |f_n(x) - f(x)| > \varepsilon) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$. One way to proceed is note that
$$|f - g| \leq |f - f_n| + |f_n - g|,$$
and use this to show that for every $\varepsilon > 0$,
$$\mu(|f - g| > \varepsilon) \leq \mu(|f - f_n| > \frac{\varepsilon}{2}) + \mu(|f_n - g| > \frac{\varepsilon}{2}) \to 0 \text{ as } n \to \infty.$$

Another approach is to use the fact that convergence in measure implies a subsequence converges almost everywhere. You can use this to get a subsequence $f_{n_k} \to f$ a.e., and then since $f_{n_k} \to g$ in measure, there is a subsequence $f_{{n_k}_j} \to g$ a.e. Therefore $f = g$ a.e, both being a.e. limits of $f_{{n_k}_j}$.